# What is the parameter : 'Customs-fields'

Tags: custom-post-types

I don't understand how to use customs-field on register_post_type.
On Codex, for "build" an register post, there is a parameter "support" that is an array with 'customs-field" . Can you explain with example if is possible ?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

first you need to understand the `support` parameter, so from the codex:

> Register support of certain features for a given post type(s). All
>   features are directly associated with a functional area of the edit
>   screen, such as the editor or a meta box. Additionally, the
>   'revisions' feature dictates whether the post type will store
>   revisions, and the 'comments' feature dictates whether the comments
>   count will show on the edit screen.

So basically what this means is that if you register your post type with `custom-fields` in the `support` parameter of `register_post_type` eg:

```
'supports' => array('custom-fields','title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
```

your post type will support custom fields and the custom fields metabox will show on your custom post type edit screen, this one: [image: custom fields metabox]

and how to use them is another question which has a great [entry in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Custom_Fields)

Comment: Thank for your answer.
So, customs_field equal meta_box ? If i don't add custom-fields on support's array , i can't add meta_box ?

Comment: NO, custom fields equal customs fields meta_box.

Comment: OH, yes . I have tested and saw ... but have you an example to use it ?

Comment: how to use custom fields? http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Custom_Fields